# Symfony forms; Insert new relation instead of update; collection

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-forms, symfony-3.3

So I have following:

```
$builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('address', AddressType::class, [
            'property_path' => 'address'
        ])
        // TODO: Refactor to create new entities that are without ID
        ->add('person', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => PersonType::class,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'property_path' => 'persons'
        ])
    ;
```

I run my functional test as follows with given parameters and everything works as expected. The entity is getting populated with new address relation & 2 new persons inside:

```
'entity' => [
            'name' => 'Test',
            'person' => [
                [
                    'firstname' => 'one', 'lastname' => 'two'
                ], [
                    'firstname' => 'three', 'lastname' => 'four'
                ]
            ],
            'address' => [
                'street' => 'test str.',
            ]
        ]
```

Now if I run update on the same formtype with following params:

```
'entity' => [
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'Test upd',
            'person' => [
                [
                    'id' => 1, 'lastname' => 'update'
                ], [
                    'firstname' => 'new', 'lastname' => 'person'
                ]
            ]
        ]
```

What it does is: it correctly updates person with id 1. The problem is with the second one with firstname 'new' - instead of creating a new person and updating relationship it just looks for the remaining relation in 'entity' and updates the person with id 2.

Please help me find a way to properly configure this.

**UPDATE**: I can see the point in what's happening, most probably It is because the inverse side of relation of "entity" is not defined in PersonType. What would be the proper way to set up this relation field in PersonType, so it won't be recursive?

Comment: You are showing us just some array's but the question is how you process those array's (where is the code?) In every case you have to add a new element to the arrayCollection of the associated entity. That means create a new Entity and add it to the array as a new element.

Comment: well, the code won't be much of a help to you:

    $type->handleRequest($request);

        if ($type->isValid()) {

            $this->em->persist($newEntity);

            $this->em->flush();
        }